# get value from subquery in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

the thing is that i don know if there is a way to get a value from a subquery over an update operation, the query that i'm trying to do looks like this, on a example code of my model :

```
$query = "UPDATE some_table SET value_1 = ((SELECT value_2 FROM other_table WHERE id = 2) + 1) WHERE id = 2";

$this->db->query($query);
```

i hope you can help me or at least let me know an alternative way to get this using the active record

PD i'm working with the CodeIgniter Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
UPDATE some_table SET value_1 = ((SELECT value_2 FROM other_table WHERE id = 2) + 1) WHERE id = 2
```

in ActiveRecord is probably:

```
$value_2 = $this->db->get_where('other_table', array('id' => 2))[0];
$data = array('value_1', $value_2 + 1);
$this->db->update('some_table', $data, array('id' => 2));
```

Comment: do you know, what approach is the best?

Comment: I support using ActiveRecord simply because it supports maintainability. So if you need to switch to Redis or any other DB system in 2 years time, you don't need to alter your code.

Comment: @Erick Garve it`s not relevant answer of your question. There 2 queries - not single with subquery.

Comment: can you propose a different one?

Answer (score 0):

I not working with Codeigniter, but try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE some_table st SET st.value_1 = ((SELECT ot.value_2 FROM other_table ot WHERE ot.id = 2) + 1) WHERE st.id = 2";

$this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: this approach it's the same that i all ready try, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, but with alias for tables name, because you have two columns with name id by example. It's not working?